# Recommended pattern for downloading multiple files in Monotouch (async/multithreaded)

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, task-parallel-library

I have a MT app that downloads content form the internet (ex - lots of images - 10K to 5MB). One download session can represent gigabytes of data. I have wrapped the download in a Parallel.ForEach loop and that works, but doesn't seem to use any more then one thread on the device for downloading (I would like at least two to reduce the download time).

Note: Parallel.ForEach **does** create multiple threads in the simulator. Should I just throw all the downloads as tasks into the thread pool? Should I spin up my own queue and threads and bypass the threadpool? I know the threadpool scales to match the device, so that might not be the best option.

Comment: `ThreadPool` and `Parallel.ForEach` try to use the optimal number of threads to efficiently use the CPU. They have no idea how many threads are needed to efficiently download files. (At least that's how it works in .Net on Windows, I have no experience with MonoTouch.)

Comment: The above is **right** on target and should be an (even **the**) answer. It's easy to create too many threads without downloading things any faster (and it's even more problematic on mobile device which have less memory/CPU/bandwidth than desktops).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to IO, only the application developer knows how much parallelism he wants. Don't rely on the TPL for that - it knows nothing about IO.

Create the right amount of IO parallelism yourself by starting the correct number of tasks manually, using PLINQ with an exact degree of parallelism or using async IO (which is thread-less).

Answer (score 1):

Are you downloading via HTTP? I've found the WebClient class to work well for the type of thing you're describing.

Something like:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
client.DownloadFileAsync("http://stackoverflow.com", "test.txt");
```

```
void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //file finished downloading
}
```

This way there's no need to manage the threads yourself.

Also if you want to read the data from the file right away you might just want to use

```
DownloadDataAsync
```

And save the file yourself.

Comment: Does this address the parallelism issue?

Comment: DownloadFileAsync will launch a new thread. I guess my answer to "Should I spin up my own queue and threads and bypass the threadpool" is yes, although I believe DownloadFileAsync will use a thread from the threadpool.